# For a transfer applicant, is it wise to ask the university applied to, not to contact my current one?

Tags: application, transfer-student

Premise that I'm already an undergraduate at a university, but want to change to a UK university. Call the Current uni, C. Call the university that I'm Applying to, A.

Is it acceptable and reasonable to ask A not to contact C without my permission? I don't look suspicious or weird to A, but I will fret about repercussions from C, dislikes students changing unis during their course, if C learns about my application to A.

I'm completely OK for A to ask me to send A reasonable details about me directly from C or my referee, like grade transcripts, without going through me. Privacy is still kept because my referee already knows and because only the transcript office at C is probably bound by privacy rules. Even then, the transcript office will only know that I've something to do with A, but not what. But I DON'T want A to write C's student office, registrar, departmental office, relevant undergraduate faculty, ... like underneath.

> 'Dear C, This is A. Because Frank is applying to A to change subjects, therefore can you please tell us ...? Also, can you please ask Frank to send us ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is wise. Such things would probably do more harm to your case. I see no reason for C to be "repercussive" to students trying to transfer. I've heard about particular professors to act that way, but never about institutions. In any case, their repercussions towards you are clearly an issue and should be addressed. However, this has nothing to do with the institution A, which will follow its procedures. If you issued such request to A, they would probably think that you have something to hide.

As for C, you should clearly transfer to another institution if the claims you have laid out are true. Don't fret about what they will think. It is your education and your life and you are free to make decisions which suit you best.